# SQL Server Table locked when error raised from trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, transactions

I have created a small application in C#. In that I have coded `try...catch` blocks on saving as follows.

```
Try
{
    command.BeginTransection();
    //execute statements here

    command.commit();
}
Catch
    //Here I get error, which is raised from Sql trigger
    command.rollback();
Finally
```

In my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[table_insert]
ON [table] FOR INSERT
BEGIN
   //If some condition not matched as per my criteria, I have raise error from trigger
   RAISEERROR
END;
```

I am getting error in my C# code, and I am rollback my transaction, but still my table is showing locked, and another user work on my application from network getting "connection timeout" error.

So, I don't understand what is the problem is?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: 
[SQL Transactions with Rollback in C#][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912112/c-sharp-rollback-sqltransaction-in-catch-block-problem-with-object-accessabi

Comment: @user3399857, that is different issue.